# sa account Password as NULL in SQL 2012 -- Passwords resets every three hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

Currently i am using SQL Express edition 2012. I want to set sa account password as NULL (empty password). I can set the password as NULL and i can login with that. but after 3 hours password resets and then i cant login with null password.

Anyone can help how to disable the automatically reset password or how to increase the reset time. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: *Please address this issue* That sounds like your job

Comment: This is your problem not ours. even though you might be frustrated try to remember to ask for help rather than dumping it on our desk and walking away - edit your post and then we will see how we can help.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe Stack Overflow puts `mysql` in "Suggested tags" box for questions that are related to SQL. So users might be tempted to accept SO's suggestions, even if they're meaningless.

Comment: such an awful idea to have no password on the sa account.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to uncheck the "Check Password Policy" of the sa account or do something like the statement below.

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

The sa account by default enables the password policy enforcement which by design prevents null or empty passwords.

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms161959.aspx

As a side note, not sure why you want to disable policy enforcement on sa account. Best practice is usually just to disable the account altogether.